# navigate an html collection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a simple program in jQuery but I find it difficult to handle collection well.

I have a list of div elements with the same class, and I gather them with this line of code:

```
var collection = $('.className').get();
```

If I print the collection I get the following:

```
w.fn.init(3) [div.className, div.className, div.className, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

Which makes total sense to me. Now I want that when a user click on such element it removes the clicked element from the collection, but I can't find a way to identify the element clicked in the collection. I tried with `index()`:

```
collection.map((el) => {
    console.log(el.index())
});
```

it returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: el.index is not a function
>       at coll.map.el (:2:8)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at :1:6

How can I identify the element clicked with something unique that can allow me to remove that div from the collection?

Comment: It's because `get()` converts the jQuery objects to Element objects and they do not have a `index()` method. You say you want to 'remove the elements from the collection when clicked'. The standard JS/jQuery way of doing this would be the inverse of what you currently have. That would be to add/remove the class when clicking the elements, then build the collection later on at the point when it's required for use - such as when a form is submit. This way you don't have to maintain the collection and worry about it going out of sync with the UI.

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the collection, or from the page?

Comment: I want to keep it on the page, but I want to track what has been clicked in the collection array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track to an array like this - is there a reason you need to track it in that particular type of collection?

```
var tracking = [];
$('.test').on('click', function(){
  tracking.push($(this).index());
  $.unique(tracking);
  $('.result').html(JSON.stringify(tracking));
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0v849spq/1/

Comment: That's the thing, I want to keep it on the page, but I want to update my collection!

Comment: I understand now, I've updated my answer. Hopefully it helps some. This just tracks it in an array, but you can easily track that back to any type of collection.